# Spring data JPA java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity

Tags: spring, jpa, entity, spring-data-jpa

I have created spring data JPA sample project. I used eclips for this. There are two projects, one is domain object project which has only annotated entity classes.  Other project is actual spring data jpa project and it has a dependency for the project one. Actually it gets domain project entity classes via maven dependency.

Project 1 : hrm-domain

Entity class :

```
package com.hrm.ws.data.domain;

import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.Table;



@Entity(name = "Employee")
@Table(name = "employee")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Employee {

    protected long id;

    protected String firstName;

    protected String lastName;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the id property.
     * 
     */
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", scale = 0)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
```

Project 2 : hrm-ws-service

persistance-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">


        <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
            <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
            <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
            <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
        </bean>

        <jpa:repositories base-package="com.hrm.ws.data.repository" />


        <bean id="employeeDao" class="com.hrm.ws.data.repository.EmployeeRepositoryImpl"/>      


        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">

              <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
              <property name="jpaDialect">
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
              </property>

        </bean>

        <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">

              <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

              <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                  <property name="generateDdl" value="${jdbc.generateDdl}" />
                  <property name="showSql" value="${jdbc.showSql}"/>
                </bean>
              </property>
              <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="jpa.sample" />

        </bean>

</beans>
```

So the setup for my packages is as follows:

src/main/java - contains the spring repository

src/main/resources - contains application context

src/test/java - contains unit tests

And dependency for the project 1 (hrm-domain)

My problem is when I run this project I am getting error as follows:

```
... 38 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity: class com.hrm.ws.data.domain.Employee
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1429)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:844)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:786)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:474)
    ... 40 more


**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity: class** com.hrm.ws.data.domain.Employee
    at org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.entity(MetamodelImpl.java:160)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:52)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getMetadata(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:61)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:145)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:83)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:66)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:146)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:120)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:39)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
    ... 48 more
```

I am wondering about this issue, because when I put domain object (Employee.java)  in my spring project it self rather separate jar it works fine. This issue only happens it gives as a separate jar.  If any one has experience about  scenario like that please give me a help.

Comment: It is invisible from sample, but do Employee have a constructor?

Comment: please, provide the contents of the `persistence.xml`. The persistence unit name 'jpa.sample', in the bean entityManagerFactory, is it correct?

Comment: I also have the same problem, could you figure out what the problem was? My project has the annotated classes in a separated maven jpa-facet project (which is referenced from the maven spring based project)

Comment: Note that entities declared in upstream projects need to be listed in the persistence-unit of the persistence.xml file of the downstream project, in order for the downstream project to use it.

Comment: May not be related to your problem, but if you have upgraded java to java 8 then spring3 doesn't work. You must upgrade to spring 4 check the given post here Steps to fix the issue given in this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/30204461/526438

Answer (score 7):

I also had the same problem. Mine was that I didn't supply the `packagesToScan` property in the `entityManagerFactory` bean, so Spring couldn't load the Entities. Check out the `emf` bean declaration in your spring configuration xml. The following is a EMF declaration I hope it could help you to get rid the error:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.hrm.ws.data.domain" />
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: I don't have a spring xml configuration file since I'm exclusively using annotations for my bean configuration. Is there a way to do this using annotations with hibernate 5.2.2?

Answer (score 1):

You're not scanning the com.hrm.ws.data.domain package for beans annotated with @Entity so the spring container has no knowledge of your entities and therefore producing an exception. Add the following lines to your persistance-context.xml config file:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.hrm.ws.data.domain" />
```

You'll also need to change your root xml element as follows so it the context elements are recognized:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
```

And, if you haven't already, add the spring-context dependency to your pom file.

Comment: I also have the same problem, what if the entity annotated classes are in another maven project (that of course is referenced from the spring based project)? I make what you said but I keep getting the same error as @Hasitha does... What else could it be?

Comment: The maven project with the entities should define a context of its own and scan the packages where the annotated entities exist. The other project (consumer of the one with the entities, which I'm assuming is a main project?) should reference the other context by importing the spring xml file. Here's an example on how to do this: http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-javaconfig-import-example/. That said, it's hard to tell what's actually going on without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the following option :-

1. context:component-scan
       base-package="Your Base Package Name" in spring.xml file
2. set packagesToScan property on the entityManagerFactory
3. use persistence.xml and list all entities there.